# Getting UITableViewCell from UIAccessibilityElement

Tags: uitableview, uiaccessibility, kif

I'm using the KIF framework and from various APIs I can fetch the `UITableViewCellAccessibilityElement` for a specific `UITableViewCell` subclass called `RDTokenCell`.

```
(lldb) po element
[UITableViewCellAccessibilityElement - 0x148c9f30] <RDTokenCell: 0x14bf6db0;
baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 50);
text = 'Fake Group 331'; autoresize = W;
layer = <CALayer: 0x14bf6f80>>) <NSIndexPath: 0x1596e2b0>
{length = 2, path = 0 - 0} - Recipient Fake Group 331
```

However, when I call `element.accessibilityContainer` it returns the containing `UITableView` and not the `UITableViewCell` that the element refers to.

Why is this and how can I fetch the cell rather than the table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an additional `UIView` covering the `UITableViewCell` until closed by pressing an `X` button in my UI. Apparently, the blocking `UIView` forced the `UITableViewCell`'s `accessibilityContainer` to the parent `UITableView`.

I forced `KIF` to first close the top level `UIView` by instructing it to press the `X` button and then all the `UITableViewCell`s became accessible.

Moral of the story, if a `UIView` is covering an accessibility element then the accessibility container may default to the superview of the contained element instead.